# Prove that the number of pairs in a string starting and ending with $1$ is $\frac{m(m-1)}{2}$

Tags: combinatorics

In a given binary string, we have to find the number of pairs starting and ending with $1$.
By analysis the solution of this problem is $\frac{m(m-1)}{2}$ where $m$ is the number of $1$'s in the string.

How do we mathematically prove the above statement?

Comment: If you count the string $1$ as starting and ending with $1$ then $m(m-1)/2$ is too few

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean substrings of length at least 2. In that case, your formula is simply $m \choose 2$ which makes sense: you want all substrings beginning and ending with 1 of length at least 2. That is, you need to count the number of distinct pairs of 1's. This is exactly that $m \choose 2$ gives you.